# Generating a HTML table from polars DataFrame (row iterator)

Tags: python-polars

I want to generate a HTML table report (using a template engine) from polars DataFrame (something like streamlit).

But the iterator in polars DataFrame is column wise and I haven't found any API to iterate the rows for a polars DataFrame (other than using something like `.to_dicts()`).

With pandas I usually do `for row in df.itertuples(): ...`. This works well because I can access the column value by name using `row.col`.

I can think of two options

1. Use `pl.DataFrame(...).to_pandas().itertuples()`
2. Write custom iterator class

Is there a solution where we can iterate polars DataFrame row wise without having to convert it or having to write a custom iterator class?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.rows()`?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see `df.rows()` before. Two problems with it though, (1) it is not an iterator, thus it requires double the memory usage if we just want to process the rows (2) it is a plain tuple so we have to manually zip it or convert to a namedtuple manually.

Comment: Ah okay - there is also `.row()` to get a single row - it still returns a tuple though.

Comment: I find using .to_pandas() as a compatibility layer works fine, unless you have some real performance issues.

Comment: A dataframe is a table. Whether it is stored by row or column is an implementation detail. I find it weird having to convert the whole data just to iterate the rows.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting a html table

You can utilize the html table that polars creates for rendering in jupyter notebooks.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, None],
    "b": [1, None, None],
})

df._repr_html_()
```

```html
<div>\n<style scoped>\n    .dataframe tbody tr th:only-of-type {\n        vertical-align: middle;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe tbody tr th {\n        vertical-align: top;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe thead th {\n        text-align: right;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe td {\n        white-space: pre;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe td {\n        padding-top: 0;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe td {\n        padding-bottom: 0;\n    }\n\n    .dataframe td {\n        line-height: 95%;\n    }\n</style>\n<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n<small>shape: (3, 2)</small>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th>\na\n</th>\n<th>\nb\n</th>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>\ni64\n</td>\n<td>\ni64\n</td>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>\n1\n</td>\n<td>\n1\n</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>\n2\n</td>\n<td>\nnull\n</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>\nnull\n</td>\n<td>\nnull\n</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n</div>
```

### Iterating rows

If you want an iterator over rows it is very easy to create one in Python.

```py
import polars as pl
from typing import Tuple, Any

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, None],
    "b": [1, None, None],
})


def iterrows(df: pl.DataFrame) -> Tuple[Any]:
    for i in range(df.height):
        yield df.row(i)
        
        
gen = iterrows(df)

next(gen)  # returns (1, 1)
next(gen)  # returns (2, None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about `_repr_html()`. Might be good for quick printing of DataFrame in the template. Yes, it not is difficult to create the iterator. By asking this question I hope to add to the fact that iterating the rows is a common usage and that polars might in the future add something like `.itertuples()`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ritchie46 answer

```py
import polars as pl
from collections import namedtuple


def itertuples(df):
    tup = namedtuple('PolarsRow', df.columns)
    for i in range(df.height):
        yield tup(*df.row(i))

pl.DataFrame.itertuples = itertuples

df = pl.DataFrame(...)
for tup in df.itertuples():
    print(tup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Polars (now) supports an [inter_rows method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.iter_rows.html). There are also parameters which will allow you to optimize your memory consumption, which isn't trivial when working with big dataframes.

Beware of the warning though :

> Row iteration is not optimal as the underlying data is stored in columnar form; where possible, prefer export via one of the dedicated export/output methods that deals with columnar data.